# Spring Integration Queue-Channel Capacity wrong

Tags: spring-integration, message-queue

I play more with spring integration what I am very interested in, but have for my opinion a strange behaviour I cannot find an answer for it.

I have a simple application using Queue-Channel:

```
<int:channel id="ticketChannel" datatype="ch.elca.prototype.model.Ticket">
    <int:queue capacity="1"/>
</int:channel>
```

I also tried Rendezvous-Queue with same effect:

```
<int:channel id="ticketChannel" datatype="ch.elca.prototype.model.Ticket">
    <int:rendezvous-queue/>
</int:channel>
```

With my understanding, now it should be only be possible to move one message in one time in that channel. Maybe 2, if you think you have one additional capacity. I am not sure how to read it. BUT I can send four times into that channel without consuming, thats a litte bit strange to me and I dont understand capacity then.

See following:

**Main Application:**
Here I stream 10 Tickets and call openTicket for each:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SassSimulatorApplication2.class, args)) {
        final TicketGenerator generator = context.getBean(TicketGenerator.class);
        final ProblemReporter reporter = context.getBean(ProblemReporter.class);
        generator.createTickets().limit(10).forEach(reporter::openTicket);
        context.close();
    }
}
```

**ProblemReporter:**

```
public class ProblemReporter {
    private volatile QueueChannel channel;

    public synchronized void openTicket(final Ticket ticket){
        final Message<Ticket> build = TicketMessageBuilder.buildMessage(ticket);
        boolean send = channel.send(build);

        System.out.println("send: " + send);
        System.out.println("getQueueSize: " + channel.getQueueSize());
        System.out.println("getSendCount: " + channel.getSendCount());
        System.out.println("getReceiveCount: " + channel.getReceiveCount());
        System.out.println("getSendErrorCount: " + channel.getSendErrorCount());
        System.out.println("getRemainingCapacity: " + channel.getRemainingCapacity());
    }

    @Value("#{ticketChannel}")
    public void setChannel(final QueueChannel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }
}
```

When starting application I get following:

```
send: true
getQueueSize: 0
getSendCount: 0
getReceiveCount: 0
getSendErrorCount: 0
getRemainingCapacity: 1

send: true
getQueueSize: 0
getSendCount: 0
getReceiveCount: 0
getSendErrorCount: 0
getRemainingCapacity: 1

send: true
getQueueSize: 1
getSendCount: 0
getReceiveCount: 0
getSendErrorCount: 0
getRemainingCapacity: 0

send: true
getQueueSize: 1
getSendCount: 0
getReceiveCount: 0
getSendErrorCount: 0
getRemainingCapacity: 0
```

I am using Spring-Boot 1.3.3, Sprint-Integration 4.2.5.RELEASE. I also tried Spring-Boot 1.2.8 with Spring-Integration 4.1.9.

Is that expected behaviour???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `channel.send(build, 30000);` is done against the `local` variable, not shared `bean`.
My test-case looks like:

```
QueueChannel channel = new QueueChannel(3);

IntStream.range(0, 4)
        .forEach(i -> {
            boolean send = channel.send(new GenericMessage<>("test-" + i), 100);
            System.out.println("send: " + send);
            System.out.println("getQueueSize: " + channel.getQueueSize());
            System.out.println("getRemainingCapacity: " + channel.getRemainingCapacity());
        });
```

And the result is:

```
send: true
getQueueSize: 1
getRemainingCapacity: 2
send: true
getQueueSize: 2
getRemainingCapacity: 1
send: true
getQueueSize: 3
getRemainingCapacity: 0
send: false
getQueueSize: 3
getRemainingCapacity: 0
```

Note: the `sendCount` (and similar) can be enabled only via `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport` or `@EnableIntegrationManagement`.
See [Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metrics-management) in the Reference Manual.

Also you can find some test-cases on the matter in the Framework, e.g. [`QueueChannelTests`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/channel/QueueChannelTests.java).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am not sure what you mean with not shared bean. I extended my class in my quesion above. I inject the channel by @Value, so it is managed by Spring. When I chance capacity to eg. 50, then I get 200 into the channel ...

Comment: OK. Since it looks like a Spring Boot application it would be great if you share it somewhere on GitHub and we'll play with it locally.

Comment: I really sorry, it was really silly from me. I had already a Transformator, and he already consume the ticket, so it was one space again available in the queue. So embarrassing, thanks for helping.

Comment: Thats not a question of respect. The issue was somewhere else, but for being helpful I accept you answer :-)